Why is chrome trying to load images with just `data-src` attribute?
I tried the following code on codepen
<img data-src="not_supposed_to_load">

Which, as far as I know, shouldn't fire any network request. But when I check chrome console:

I also checked the source of the error:

And checked the initiator of the request in network tab, which doesn't show any javascript trace:

I tested this on firefox and it doesn't fire any network request. It seems this is only on chrome. Also looked for any chrome features that use data-src for lazyloading, but I didn't find anything that would explain this behavior... Is this some chrome's bug?

That's really curious. In addition to your tests, I noted that if you have both a src and a data-src attribute then it ignores the data-src.  Also, it loads them even if they are off-screen, so it doesn't seem like an undocumented lazyloading thing.

Indeed, I didn't test to see if this would be a lazyloading mechanism... Now it's even more intriguing to me...

No idea, but did you just try renaming the attribute? Seems like the simpliest solution instead of wondering why Chromium does Chromium things. As long as it works ofc.

Of course I knew about renaming the attribute! But where's the fun of accepting something as it is and move on when you can get the root cause of something? Don't you think haha

I guess that codepen uses an older Chromium version that caches the data-src attribute. It is now deprecated on the current Chrome engine.
